# JavaScript problems in one IIS server but not another

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iis, content-management-system, episerver

I have a problem that only occurs in one environment. On this particular page, somewhere in the top half of the  element, an array is created and populated. This is later used in the onfocus event handlers of various controls. I use Firebug to debug the page and discovered the problem. In our dev environment the array is indeed created and populated. In our staging environment this block of script is not executed! I put a break point where the array is instantiated and it's never hit in staging, but is hit in dev.

I'm really puzzled what aspects of the two environments can possibly affect this? We use aptimize on the staging box but it has been turned off for this particular website. I compared the page sources and they're identical! The only difference is bits of content since they are served by a CMS.

Any ideas please? I'm quite stuck on this.

Cheers,
Dany.

Comment: Do you get any script errors?

Comment: Are the two environments using the same database?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Net tab of Firebug and check for external file requests giving errors. Might be a httphandler that is called but has not been configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're testing with IE8?  If so, you may need to turn compatibility view off by default for Intranet sites.